# "isn't about" vs. "doesn't refer to"

Tags: prepositions

Does "isn't about" mean the same as "doesn't refer to" in this sentence?

> Missing someone **isn't about** how long it has been since you've seen them, or the length of time you talked.
>   It's about that very moment when you're doing something, and you wish they were right there with you.

Comment: The idiom is: to be about something. This movie is about love. This book is about science. No, it does not mean the same thing as: refer to.

Comment: **pertain to** would be better than **refer to**, because references can be merely in passing. The complement of **about** is a topic, the main focus.  *This letter is about your sister and her new job. It is not about your brother.*

Answer (score 2):

They definitely don't mean exactly the same thing, though they are related.

- If something "is about" something, it means that other thing is the main subject. Many times this main subject is different than, or at least additional to, what we see on a surface level. Take the book "To Kill a Mockingbird." It's a story about a girl growing up in a town, and her father Atticus and friends, and also a black man named Tom. But it's also about racism, and not just in that town: the racism that we all feel at some level.
- If something "refers to" something, it just makes a reference. To continue the example, "To Kill a Mockingbird" could be said to "refer to" trial proceedings, because a trial does figure prominently. But you would not say trial proceedings are what the book/movie is "about". They're important to the plot, but they're really incidental.

Edit to take the added example in the question into account: This is a perfect illustration. You're saying you don't define how much you miss somebody by how long it's been since you saw them: you define how much you miss them by wishing they were there with you.

Comment: Yes, "is defined by" is a good paraphrase. Another (in my opinion ideal) paraphrase would be: "Missing someone isn't a question of.."

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/about      open the link and see the second one.  is that what isnt about mean in the sentence mentioned above

Comment: In the example sentence "Leadership is about the ability to implement change" ots